# DB2 JDBC Driver (Type 4) hangs on Execute()

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere, execute

I am executing a series of sql statements using a JDBC connection on a DB2 server. On the last `execute()` of the simple sql: `DELETE FROM MYTABLE`, the thread gets hung for a long period of time even if the table somply contains a single record.

The application server I am using is WAS. I wonder if this is an issue specific to WAS and DB2 combination as the same code works on other environments.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Besides any of the other answers, could we see some of your java code, just to spot-check it?

Comment: i will post it in some time but do remember that this code works on all other configurations like sql server +WAS, Oracle +WAS, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you issue the command directly from the CLP? It could be other problem such as:

- Transaction log problem: There are a lot of rows to delete, and this takes time. Also, the transaction logs have reached the limit, and the database does not do a rollback but waits for empty log freed by other transactions.
- Lock problem (concurrency): some of the rows your are trying to delete have locks in other transactions, and the applications has to wait to release them (lock wait)

Also, try to do frequent commits.

Comment: plz check my reply to previous answer

Comment: I tried on my dev environment which is not being used by anybody else

Comment: are you completly sure, did you execute a "db2pd -wlocks"? what is the result? Probably, you are locking the row from another connection, such as the control center.

Comment: @MozenRath I'm working with DB2 and these problems always occurs when the table is locked by a simple select command used in another application. Make sure the table isn't locked and attempt to delete the record again.

Comment: it is as you guys said. There was another connection that locked the table. This connection was from the same application. normally you would think this connection would be destroyed by gc but it was not. I added code to close it and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Deleting rows in a database can be a terrible work: don't forget the database server will log all the data of the table in case of a ROLLBACK. Then I assume the problem is coming from the database especially if the table has many rows.

Have you tried to run manually all the SQL requests yourself in an interactive environment?

Comment: as i have mentioned in the question, there is only a single record in the table